# SQL query assistance please

Tags: sql

I'm still grasping the basics of sql. Any help much appreciated.

The table is TeamRankings. The columns are as follows:

```
score | qualities_id | team_id | year | source_id
```

Teams are scored with respect to different qualities for specific years. Note that a given team can can be assigned multiple scores (each one would be from a different source). Likewise, a given team might not have any scores at all for given year.

Here's the problem:

Given a single quality, a list of teams, and a list of years, I want to find a single score for each team/year. In the event that a given team/year has scores available from multiple sources, I'd like to chose the score with the lowest source_id.

I'm guessing that the way to do this is to `GROUP BY` team_id, year, quality_id, and then somehow filter out the higher source ids. But I'm confused as to where that filtering happens. It's not in the `HAVING` clause, or the `WHERE` clause, correct? Do I need a subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join with a grouped version of the table:

```
select t.* from TeamRankings t
inner join (select team_id, year, min(source_id) as minSource
            from TeamRankings group by team_id, year) f
on t.team_id = f.team_id AND t.year = f.year AND t.source_id = f.minSource
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT score, team_id, year, min(source_id)
FROM TeamRankings
GROUP BY score, team_id, year
WHERE qualities_id=1
```